# Hyper-V broken after uninstalling VMWare Player

Tags: hyper-v

Im having a serious problem...

I tried to install VMWare Player on WS2012R2 that has the Hyper-V role enabled and when I tried to turn on a VM in Player, it says it wasnt compatible so I reinstalled it.

WS2012R2 BSOD. Thats when it all started...

So basically how do I remove VMWare Player and all its related drivers (it seems that is what is conflicting with Hyper-V)?

Comment: Server 2012 r2, vmware end user software and hyper-v native hypervisor - I would nuke the install (reinstall) and not bother with fixing.

Comment: Its kind of my Hyper-V host with my domain controller being a guest so yeah, no... The problem right now is that it thinks that there is a Synthetic Ethernet Port that has another instance ID so it cannot boot up. How do I remove all my network instances?

Comment: `I tried to install VMWare Player on WS2012R2 that has the Hyper-V role enabled` - That was kind of a dumb thing to do. Why would you install a Type 2 hypervisor on top of a Type 1 hypervisor? As TomTom stated, nuke the server and start over.

Comment: It was obviously a error on my fault. It is imposible to nuke the server and start over as this is a Hyper-V host running a guest which is the domain controller. I hope you understand what you are asking me to do...

Comment: Reinstalling the host is quite possibly the _only_ way to recover from this. Store the VHDs for your VMs somewhere else while performing the reinstall, or migrate them to another Hyper-V host.

Comment: Solved it finally.

Comment: Why not post the solution here as an answer, as no one else wanted to provide much help.

Comment: @DougLuxem I feel that everyone has been incredibely rude not even attempting to post workarounds and/or alternative solutions other than "nuking it". Honestly, if they are rude with me, I feel I should be rude with them. It will get me downvotes but thats how I honestly feel, I apoligize.